# KAA Machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, kaa

How a machine learning algorithm(Present in Spark MLlib) can be applied to Data collected from sensors in KAA. I haven't found any such use case built on KAA. My requirement is to collect the live streams of data, processing and cleaning the same and applying a machine leaning algorithm in KAA.
I have done this by collecting the data using Apache nifi and through Kafka passing the data to Spark Streaming Application on which I am applying the machine learning algorithm.

I want to perform the same in KAA as an IoT platform.